# System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean equivalent in .net 6

Tags: .net, boolean, converters, system.data, dnf

There is a converter function in `System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean` in .net Framework 4.8. I cannot find this namespace in .net 6.  Does anybody know where it was moved to?

We are specifically looking for a logic expression to DNF format.

I have looked in assorted places but have not been able to locate it.

Comment: Isn't everything in there `internal` anyway? What were you using in there?

Comment: I'm trying to get to the converter this link.  I can't find it moved to another spot but I feel certain MS didn't just drop it from the system.
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Entity/System/Data/Common/Utils/Boolean/Converter.cs

Comment: Again, it's an internal class. They have no obligation to ensure it stays available between releases.